# Why does iterating over the same recordset with `mysql_fetch_assoc()` fail when using it more than once?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
session_start();

include '../dbconnect_form_fields.php';

$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM form_fields") or die(mysql_error());
echo "<form id='list' action='form_calc.php' method='post'>
<table width='100%' border='1'>
<tr>";
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++) {
    echo "<td><select>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){ 
        echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['field']." ".$row['price']."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>
</td>";
}
?>
```

Why does this code produce one correct select box, and one empty select box?

I want it to correctly display two identical select boxes, yet it doesn't work unless I create 2 different variables each accessing the database for the same information.

Comment: Are both select boxes supposed to contain the same information?  Also, are you sure that the database is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running over all database results with the `While` loop. That's why the second iteration of the `for` loop will have no database results available anymore.

You can work around that by either storing the data in an array first, or with this ugly kludge:

```
 mysql_data_seek($res, 0);
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
```

That resets the pointer (what @alex said), so you can receive the same results twice. (Might be ok here, because the mysql interface likely caches the data anyway.)

Answer (score 3):

Because `mysql_fetch_assoc()` is internally incrementing its pointer in the results until it gets to the end and returns `FALSE`. You'd need to reset it to start iterating through it again.

The easy answer would be to build a string and `echo` it twice.

The best advice I could give you is to study [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and use it.

Comment: Thnx alex, i was suspecting it was something like that. Ill read through your link. Your a champ!

Comment: +1 for suggesting PDO.  A bit of `htmlspecialchars()` would help too.

Answer (score 1):

> Blockquote
>   mysql_fetch_assoc() Returns an associative array that
>   corresponds to the fetched row and
>   moves the internal data pointer ahead.

[More info on mysql_fetch_assoc() can be found here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

So construct a string as it uses up all the input:

```
$str = "";    
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){ 
        $str .= "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['field']." ".$row['price']."</option>";
}

echo $str;
echo $str;
```

The:

```
 .=
```

bit is short hand for add to the end of the variable. Another way of writing it would be:

```
$str = $str . "something";
```

This all could be made much more elegant, but as you're learning I will let you work that out in good time :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
session_start();

include '../dbconnect_form_fields.php';

$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM form_fields") or die(mysql_error());
$options = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){ 
            $options[] = "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['field']." ".$row['price']."</option>";
}
echo "<form id='list' action='form_calc.php' method='post'>
<table width='100%' border='1'>
<tr>";
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++) {
    echo "<td><select>";
    echo $options;
    }
    echo "</select>
</td>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hey flipper, I did originally try that, but i decied that if i wanted 6 or more fields, i didn't want to access the DB over and over again... Any solutions from that perspective?

Comment: I am confused by what you mean 6 or more fields.  But look at my edit.  Now it just accesses one time.  Also, whoever devoted my answer; why?